# How can I map the first instance of a value to a particular mapping and any subsequent instance of the same value to a different mapping?

Tags: python, pandas

I am working with a pandas dataframe, where I have 4 columns; `trade_type`, `issue_status`, `market_phase`, `trading_state`. And the dataframe is called `market_info_df`.

I want to apply the below mapping/logic to map `trade_type`, but I am not sure how to include `trade_type` in the logic. I have the following so far:

```
market_info_df.loc[market_info_df['issue_status' == '10', 'market_phase' == '0', 'trading_state' == '  ']].iloc[0] = OPENING_AUCTION

market_info_df.loc[market_info_df['issue_status' == '10', 'market_phase' == '0', 'trading_state' == '  ']].iloc[1:] = INTRADAY_AUCTION
```

This is what I am trying to achieve:

- When `issue_status=='10'` and `'market_phase' == '0'` and `'trading_state' == '  '`, I am want to map the value of `trade_type` to `OPENING_AUCTION`, for the **first instance** when `'market_phase' == '0'`.
  And for all remaining instances, I want to map `trade_type` to `INTRADAY_AUCTION`.

e.g:

```
row  issue_status  market_phase  trading_state                  trade_type
 0        20           0              '  '         ->        CONTINUOUS_AUCTION
 1        10           0              '  '         ->        OPENING_AUCTION
 2        20           0              '  '         ->       CONTINUOUS_AUCTION
 3        10           0              '  '         ->       INTRADAY_AUCTION
 4        10           0              '  '         ->       INTRADAY_AUCTION
 5        10           0              '  '         ->       INTRADAY_AUCTION
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the `trade_type` column to say CONTINUOUS_AUCTION for all other instances:

Create sample data

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'row': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 
                   'issue_status': [20, 10, 20, 10, 10, 10], 
                   'market_phase': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
                   'trading_state': ['  ', '  ', '  ', '  ', '  ', '  ']})
```

Create function to apply conditions

```
def determine_trade_type(row):
    if row['issue_status'] == 10 and row['market_phase'] == 0 and row['trading_state'] == '  ':
        if df[(df['issue_status'] == 10) & (df['market_phase'] == 0) & (df['trading_state'] == '  ')].index.min() == row['row']:
            return 'OPENING_AUCTION'
        else:
            return 'INTRADAY_AUCTION'
    else:
        return 'CONTINUOUS_AUCTION'
```

Create new trade_type column and show results

```
df['trade_type'] = df.apply(determine_trade_type, axis=1)

df
```